# Git did not commit a file - Now `git checkout HEAD` is missing files

Tags: git, github

I was working on my local folder.  I committed my changes with `git add .'` and `git commit -m 'message'`

Then I did `git checkout 'some previous commit'`, then did `git checkout HEAD` to go back to my latest commit.

It seems Git did not commit some files when I did `git add .`, and now files are gone.  Is there some way to go back to the local state before I first did `git checkout 'some previous commit'`?

Comment: `git checkout HEAD` is a glorified no-op. You'll still be on the previous commit. If you were on `master` before, use `git checkout master` to be on `master` again. If you were on `develop` before, use `git checkout develop`, etc. Note that you can use `git checkout -` as shorthand to mean "back to previous branch", but I'd leave that until you have a better sense of what Git is doing. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git only tracks committed state, so you can try checking out your 'message' revision by looking it up with `git reflog` (e.g. b.txt in the example below).

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline
6db772f6672b2d418e3228f2f9c95032e150d216 messsage
d8d4f93864df75f6e1ccc438db65809f2cb34330 Some prev commit

[git: master] $ ls
a.txt   b.txt

$ git checkout d8d4f93864df75f6e1ccc438db65809f2cb34330    
HEAD is now at d8d4f93... Some prev commit

[git: (d8d4f93...)] $ ls
a.txt

[git: (d8d4f93...)] $ git reflog
d8d4f93 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to d8d4f93864df75f6e1ccc438db65809f2cb34330
6db772f HEAD@{1}: commit: messsage
d8d4f93 HEAD@{2}: commit (initial): Some prev commit

[git: (d8d4f93...)] $ git checkout 6db772f
Previous HEAD position was d8d4f93... Some prev commit
HEAD is now at 6db772f... messsage

[git: (6db772f...)] $ ls
a.txt   b.txt
```

If for some reason, you haven't committed a file state you're interested, then it's lost from git. In that case your IDE can be of some help (e.g. Local History in Eclipse).

Answer (score 3):

`git checkout HEAD` never does anything.  It doesn’t change the current commit, because `HEAD` refers to the current commit, not “the tip of the most recently checked out branch”.  It changes no files because none differ between `HEAD` and itself.  (It doesn’t even enter detached-HEAD state, because `HEAD` actually refers to the current *branch* itself when one is checked out.  You can use `git checkout HEAD~0` to do that.)

The reflog of `HEAD` does maintain the history of branches checked out: you can use `@{-1}`, `@{-2}`, etc., to name them.  They count as branch names (since that’s what `HEAD` stores) for commands like `checkout` and `rebase`, but like any branch names can be used as commits for commands like `show` or `cherry-pick`.